# buttons action inside recursion templates occuring multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

```
<template name="childcardstmpl">
    <div class="cards-list child-cards-list">
        {{#each selected_children id}}
            <input type="text" id="{{_id}}" class="card-input childtitle "  autocapitalize="none" autocorrect="off" value="{{cardTitle}}">
          </div>
        {{/each}}
        <input type="button" id="" class="addCardButton createSiblingCard {{id}}" value="Add">
    </div>
    {{#if isSelected_have_children id}}
        {{#with selected_child id}}
            {{> childcardstmpl id=_id}}
        {{/with}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

I have this recusrion template, which is working fine and rendering whatever I want, I've attached events to template

```
'click .createSiblingCard':function(e,tmpl){
        console.log(this);
}
```

Suppose that recusrion templates renders

```
a > b > c > d
```

each time with the button

```
<input type="button" id="" class="addCardButton createSiblingCard {{id}}" value="Add">
```

If I click on button in **a**, the click event is firing 1 time

If I click on button in **b**, the click event is firing 2 times

If I click on button in **c**, the click event is firing 3 times

I want the button event to be fired only once no matter what place I'm in(a or b or c)

How to do that? What is the error in my code?

**EDIT**
or
Is there any other way to rewrite my recurion template, so the event only occure once.

Comment: if you click on b the event on a and b fire if you click on c all the events fire

Comment: yeah that is what happening? Why is it doing that?

Comment: Your code to generate the button is outside the loop, is that really correct if you want them to act independantly of each other?

Comment: @hochas yes it is correct it is independent to the loop, afterr displaying all cards at last I'm ading add button to add item to the above list

Comment: use prevent propagation

Comment: @hochas Tried it but it is not working